# Force quit OS X app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, daemon

Which is the best way to force quit an os x or daemon process if I know the app/daemon name (the name that appears in activity monitor)?

I am using objective C for coding.

Comment: why you want to force quit?

Comment: you can kill using `PID` (Process ID), but i'm not sure whether you can do it using Objective C or within your App.

Comment: You can use kill from NSTask but NSWorkSpace should provide enough for most uses otherwise all of BSD is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use Applescript to do that:

```
//tell Application to quit
NSAppleScript* restartApp = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"ApplicationName\" to quit"];
[restartApp executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

If the app is not responding you may try

```
// define command
NSString* appName = @"Finder";
NSString* killCommand = [@"/usr/bin/killall " stringByAppendingString:appName];

// execute shell command
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
[task setArguments:@[ @"-c", killCommand]];
[task launch];
```

which kills the app.

Good luck

Comment: Apple Script will not work in case if app or process is not responding

Comment: Yes, you can, but `NSTask` with `killall app_name` will do it better :)